# Using href with php and html

Tags: php, html, href

I'm trying to print in a table some rows and i want to print the variable .$row['web']. as a link.

The code is:

```
while($row = $sql_esp->fetch_array())
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['place']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['web']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['note']."</td>";
    echo "</tr></tbody</table>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

I tried to change this line:

```
echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>".$row['web']."</td>";
```

in:

```
echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><a href='".$row['web']."'></td>";
```

But it doesn't work. How can i fix?

Comment: And what's the link destination?

Comment: close your `a` like `echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><a href='".$row['web']."'>'.$row['web'].'</a></td>";` see [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: </tbody</table> should be out of while loop

Comment: echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><a 
    href='".$row['web']."'>".$row['web']."</a></td>";

In this way works.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't `echo` HTML elements, you should print the HTML in plain HTML and then `echo` in the variables with PHP; E.G: `<td style="border: 1px solid black;"><?=$row['name'];?></td>`

Answer (score 4):

`<a>` tag needs a text after and a closing `</a>` so:

```
echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'><a href='".$row['web']."'>".$row['web']."</a></td>";
```